# Boundedness Condition for Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a_{n} \geq 0$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums $(s_{n}) = \Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}\Big)$ is bounded.

I can prove the result. But why is it that we need the condition $a_{n} \geq 0$? Doesn't the result also hold if we have $a_{n} \leq 0$?

Comment: You need either that ALL $a_n$ are positive or that ALL $a_n$ are negative. Check $a_n=(-1)^n$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, so the result will hold if we do have $a_{n} \leq 0 $?

Comment: Try $a_n=(-1)^n$

Comment: It is enough that the general term have ultimately a constant sign.

Comment: Got it! Thanks all.